# Index needs sorting help!

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want my index which is mixed up (i just sorted out ratings from highest to lowest) to be in ascending (sorted) order corresponding to my sorted ratings. How can I do that?[image]

Answer (score 1):

After sorting, try:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT mate :D